# Updating base window's tags from the modal dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, colorbox

Is it possible to update base page's html attributes from the modal window?

I mean, i have a page "a.php", when user clicks a link in "a.php", a colorbox modal dialog opens. I do some ajax work on that modal dialog. At the end of that ajax work i want to update "button" tags of "a.php". Can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.. you don't really provide much for us to go, but essentially YES, a ColorBox window is just a javascript child window of the base page -- a.php, in your case.  Using standard js syntax you can access any of the parent's properties by saying, for instance,

```
parent.element.attribute = some_value
```

For example,

```
parent.form.myInput.value = "test"
```

Additionally, you can use JQuery (you're already using with ColorBox) to select the "button tags" you are after.  If you post some code, the guidance could be more specific.